# Hibernate unique constraint exception catch

Tags: hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, exception, unique-constraint

I have a simple registration with unique constraint in some fields and I want to handle unique exceptions with friendly messages in `.jsp` page, but I don't know which exception I should involve in catch block. When I try to register a user with duplicate fields I get on console:

```
Dec 13, 2017 12:35:10 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper 
logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
Dec 13, 2017 12:35:10 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper 
logExceptions
ERROR: Duplicate entry 'admin1' for key 'username'
Dec 13, 2017 12:43:37 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper 
logExceptions


WARN: SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
Dec 13, 2017 12:43:37 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper 
logExceptions
ERROR: Duplicate entry 'edek' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Handling:

```
try 
{
   userService.registerUser(userAccount);
}
catch(?)
{
   // something like : 
   return new ModelAndView("register","uniqueErrorMessage",message); 
}
```

Comment: Did you try catching `Exception` itself?

Comment: Well, ok, it works, but I would like to differentiate which field breaks unique constraint to show clear message. And this would be misleading if any other , not connected with unique constraint, sql exception occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only one primary key in table then in exception block you can search for error code `1062` (1062 code thrown when is inserting duplicate row) in exception message and return relevant message that user already exists.. etc.

OR

You can do a `select count(*)...where username='user entered this'` before inserting and if you see result count >= 1 then return relevant message, instead of handling 
 with exceptions while inserting.